# Recorded Macro To Run On Multiple Tabs or All

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the below recorded macro, I would like to run it on multiple tabs, or if easier I would like to run on all tabs.

Few named tabs are 'Richard' 'Jamie' 'Nibz'.

```
function Week1DP() { 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  spreadsheet.getRange('F8:F17').activate();

  spreadsheet.getRange('K14:L15').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), 

  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is that you need to iterate through all the sheets with a [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop (or whatever loop you prefer):

---

**Solution for all sheets:**

You can get all the sheets with [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets):

```
function Week1DP() { 
  
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets(); // get all sheets

  sheets.forEach(sh=>{                 
      sh.getRange('K14:L15').copyTo(sh.getRange('F8:F17'),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);            
});
};
```

---

**Solution for selected sheets based on the name:**

To get the sheets by name you need to use [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename):

```
function Week1DP() { 
  
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ["Richard","Jamie","Nibz"].map(sn=>spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sn));

  sheets.forEach(sh=>{                 
      sh.getRange('K14:L15').copyTo(sh.getRange('F8:F17'),
      SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);            
});
};
```

Add or remove names in this array to include or exclude sheets: `["Richard","Jamie","Nibz"]`.